# My empty rust project wont compile, what should I do?

Tags: rust, bevy

I attempted to update my bevy dependency yesterday and everything came to a halt. I changed from version "0.1.2" to version "0.1.3." When I did this, my project stopped compiling completely. I changed the dependency back to "0.1.2" and it didn't fix the issue. I then ran rustup update and that hasn't corrected the problem either. So, finally, I cut out all of the projects code except for:

```
use bevy:: {
    prelude::*,
    input::mouse::{MouseButtonInput, MouseMotion},
};

fn main() {
  println!("Hello.");
}
```

My cargo.toml is also very simple, the only modified section is as follows:

```
[dependencies]
bevy = "0.1.2"
```

So, the error I get is as follows:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `perspective_rh` found for struct `glam::f32::mat4::Mat4` in the current scope
  --> src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\bevy_render-0.1.3\src\camera\projection.rs:22:15
   |
22 |         Mat4::perspective_rh(self.fov, self.aspect_ratio, self.near, self.far)
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |               |
   |               function or associated item not found in `glam::f32::mat4::Mat4`
   |               help: there is an associated function with a similar name: `perspective_lh`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
   = note: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
           `use bevy_math::perspective::PerspectiveRh;`
```

What should I do to resolve this?

**Edit** (Results of rustup check):

> rustup check stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc - Up to date : 1.45.2
> (d3fb005a3 2020-07-31) nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc - Up to date :
> 1.47.0-nightly (f44c6e4e2 2020-08-24)

Comment: Can you try `cargo clean` and deleting your `Cargo.lock`

Comment: Cargo clean did not work on its own but deleting Cargo.lock did work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `cargo clean` and deleting `Cargo.lock`.